# Eclipse: Supressing, "cannot be resolved to a type"

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-errors

I'm using eclipse to edit a maven project and I'm getting a lot of errors about not being able to resolve a type.  This makes sense because it really doesn't exist, the source code is auto generated only just before compilation.  Is there anyway I can suppress errors related to this specific class.

Answer (score 0):

There is an Eclipse Java preferences page that lets you specify whether specific compile errors are ERROR, WARNING or IGNORED.  This wouldn't apply to maven builds outside of Eclipse, though.